# PHP Regular Expression to get SSL Certificate Issuer / Subject

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to achieve the following, but need to use the preg_replace_callback() function or basically get the all the data in one match. Is that possible?

```
<?php

$pattern = '/([^\s]*?)\s=\s([^,]*?),/';

$string = "        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = RapidSSL RSA CA 2018";

preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
$c = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2] );

print_r( $c );
```

```
Array
(
    [C] => US
    [O] => DigiCert Inc
    [OU] => www.digicert.com
)
```

PHP Fiddle:
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/5CPWukk

I need something like this but with output similar to above:

```
  <?php
  $re = '/([^\s]*?)\s=\s([^,]*?),/';                                                                      
  $str = "        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = RapidSSL RSA CA 2018";
  preg_replace_callback ($re,   
          function ($matches) {
              var_dump($matches);              
              return null;      
          },                    
          $str
  );
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Please consider accepting the one that worked best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all` fetches all matches, while inside a `preg_replace_callback`, each match is retrieved individually, one by one.

You need to declare an array variable and pass it to the callback using `use` instruction with `&` prefix to allow updating the variable:

```
$re = '/([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*([^,]*),/';                                                                      
$str = "        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = RapidSSL RSA CA 2018";
$arr = [];
$str = preg_replace_callback ($re,   
          function ($matches) use (&$arr) {
              $arr[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
              return null;      
          },                    
          $str
);
print_r($arr); // => Array ( [C] => US [O] => DigiCert Inc [OU] => www.digicert.com )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/HohvH)

The regex is a bit enhanced to match

- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than whitespace and `=` chars
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
- `([^,]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `,`
- `,`  - a comma

Answer (score 0):

Use the PREG_SET_ORDER from preg_match_all

PHP Fidle: https://www.mycompiler.io/new/php?fork=5CPWukk

```
<?php

$pattern = '/([^\s]*?)\s=\s([^,]*?),/';
$string = "        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = RapidSSL RSA CA 2018";

preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches , PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r( $matches );
```